# Register Jersey REST Services at Startup of Spring Container

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I need to register objects as Jersey Services at runtime.
I already tried through Spring applicationContext but it is registered as a normal bean.
Something like this...

jerseyContainer.register(new Service());

```
@Path("/service")
public class Service{
    @GET
    public Thing get(){ 
        return new Thing();
    }
}
```

or some way before the Spring container finishes its startup.

Comment: Apache CXF has built-in Spring integration. If you're not bound to Jersey you may try using CXF.

Comment: I'm not tied to Jersey, but only will change it if a see a good reason, which I don't see in CXF. Do you have a example?

Answer (score 0):

the spring-jersey integration relies on a servlet

> com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet

defined in your web.xml

please refer to this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/): specifically point number 4 "Integrate Jersey with Spring"
you'll see how you can define the packages to be scanned for the resource classes to be exposed by Jersey